# ModuleNotFoundError: : No module named 'sklearn'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, python-3.11

I'm trying to write my own Machine Learning but it got an error. I'm tried to import library but it doesn't work.
Here the code:

```py
import sklearn
```

Here the error:

```
> PS D:\Dayroi\ML Learn> pip install sklearn
> Collecting sklearn
> Using cached sklearn-0.0.post5-py3-none-any.whl
> Installing collected packages: sklearn
> Successfully installed sklearn-0.0.post5
> PS D:\Dayroi\ML Learn> pip install sklearn
> Requirement already satisfied: sklearn in c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (0.0.post5)
> PS D:\Dayroi\ML Learn> & C:/Users/Administrator/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/python.exe "d:/Dayroi/ML Learn/Test/Learn.py"
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "d:\Dayroi\ML Learn\Test\Learn.py", line 5, in <module>
> import sklearn
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: the code is: #heart-disease test
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#import sklearn

data = pd.read_csv("D:\Dayroi\ML Learn\Test\heart-disease.csv")

x = data.drop("target",axis=1)
y = data["target"]

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100)
print(clf.get_params())
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
Xh, Xt, Yh, Yt = train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.2)
clf.fit(Xh,Yh)
y_prede = clf.predict(Xt)
scoreH = clf.score(Xh,Yh)
scoreT = clf.score(Xt,Yt)

Answer (score 0):

You should probably create a new environment using Anaconda distribution. Install Anaconda package from  [here](https://docs.anaconda.com/free/anaconda/install/windows/) (install accordingly to your OS distribution). Once it is installed create a new virtual environment using the following command.

```
conda create -n <env-name-of-your-choice>
```

Now install all the necessary packages (sklearn, pandas, etc.,) in this environment. Use this environment to run your python file. This will solve the issue and will not conflict

Comment: No need to create a new environment. I just install scikit-learn

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code:

```
pip install scikit-learn
```